# Join multiple row/column MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Trying to do things a bit different with a database, I got a table called "services", this table consist off pID, uID, serviceID.

Then I got a table called "user_profile", that of course got the same uID as used in the table services.

So a user can have multiple services, let's say

```
pID     uID     serviceID
1       1       101
2       1       102
3       1       104
4       2       105
```

So how do I join this to my user_profile data? I'm a bit confused about that.

Let's say somebody visits the profile with uID 1.

Then I need all the services to in the same SQL call if that's possible somehow?

Hope I make abit of sense.

Comment: Note that pID appears to serve no purpose. You have a satisfactory PK on the remaining columns without need of a surrogate. Also, this kind of problem would be covered in any beginner's book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to relate tables in SQL you must have in both tables the same column, in your example uID.
Then you write something like:
select a.uID,b.pID,b.serviceID from user_profile a left join services b on a.uID=b.uID