# Join users table with last conversation query

Tags: mysql

I need to join user info table with chat messages query for last reply.

Chat table

```
mid | sender | receiver| text    | created
  1 |  chrys |     Paul| Hello   | 2015-12-08 20:00
  2 | chrys2 |   Chrys | Hey     | 2015-12-08 20:10
```

For the last reply result i am using that script:

```
mysql_query("
select * 
    from 
        chat 
      join 
        (select user, max(created) m , COUNT(*) AS msgCount 
            from 
               (
                 (select mid, receiver user, created 
                   from chat 
                   where sender='$login_session' ) 
               union 
                 (select mid, sender user, created
                   from chat 
                   where receiver='$login_session')
                ) t1
           group by user) t2
     on ((sender='$login_session' and receiver=user) or 
         (sender=user and receiver='$login_session')) and 
         (created = m)
   order by created desc
  ");
```

My problem is that i can't figure out how to join a user info table like the following:

```
id | username | photo_url | age | etcetera.....
```

Some ideas?
All i need is to get infos about users wich are sendind messages like photo, age from the users_info table.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  You have a table of users, you have a table of messsages-- what information would you like to have when your query is done?

Comment: photo_url, age and whatever is found in users_info table.

Comment: Check if this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054587/join-multiple-row-column-mysql/41055339#41055339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile i found the answer. Here it is:

```
select c.*, u.photo
from chat c
join users u on u.username = c.sender
WHERE   (sender = '$login_session' AND receiver = '$uid') OR
        (sender = '$uid' AND receiver = '$login_session')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, you are trying to get last chat message sent or received for the logged in user.

For that,

```
select c.*
from chat c
join users u on u.id = c.receiver_id or u.id = c.sender_id
where u.id = 'SESSION.User.Id'
order by c.id desc
```

Comment: Your answer works partially. I found the answer and i posted it here. :)